# Build tags in dom with builder pattern method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am a novice. I want to use the builder pattern method in dom within a single div with id: container to create new tags and give the tags several attributes, but my code does not work and I do not know where the problem is. Please help me.

```js
class createTag {
    constructor(tagName) {
        this.tagName = document.createElement(tagName);

    }
    setTagAppend(idTag, create) {
        this.position = idTag.append(create)
        return this;
    }
    setAttribute(idTag, attribute, value) {
        this.attribute = idTag.setAttribute(attribute, value);
        return this;
    }
    getAttribute(idTag, attribute) {
        this.attribute = idTag.getAttribute(attribute);
        return this;
    }
}
const newTag = new createTag('div')
    .setTagAppend(container, newTag)
    .setAttribute("calss", "color")
```

```css
.color{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/style.css">
    <title>Log In</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
</body>
<script src="./js/script.js">
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: `idTag.append` ~ should that not be `idTag.appendChild`? And `calss` should be `class`. Where do you assign `container`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing that you are hoping to achieve?

```js
class createTag {
    constructor(tagName) {
        this.node = document.createElement(tagName);
    }
    setTagAppend(idTag) {
        idTag.appendChild(this.node);
        return this;
    }
    setAttribute(attribute, value) {
        this.node.setAttribute(attribute, value);
        return this;
    }
    getAttribute(idTag, attribute) {
        return this.node.hasAttribute(attribute) ? this.node.getAttribute(attribute) : false;
    }
}

const newTag = new createTag('div')
    .setTagAppend( document.getElementById('container') )
    .setAttribute( "class", "color" )
```

```css
#container{
  background:yellow;
  padding:1rem;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
}
.color{
  width:250px;height:5rem;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```